# Filling a complete line of rows with last_value() oracle

Tags: database, oracle, oracle11g

First of all I have this table.

```
CREATE TABLE tabla_1
(table_num NUMBER, amount NUMBER, first_name VARCHAR2(100), l_name VARCHAR2(100));

INSERT INTO tabla_1 (table_num, amount, first_name,l_name) VALUES (1,1,'Luis', 'Rosas');
INSERT INTO tabla_1 (table_num, amount, first_name,l_name) VALUES (1,1,'Carlos','Borolas');
INSERT INTO tabla_1 (table_num, amount, first_name,l_name) VALUES (1,2,'Elena','Zeta');
INSERT INTO tabla_1 (table_num, amount, first_name,l_name) VALUES (1,null,null,null);
INSERT INTO tabla_1 (table_num, amount, first_name,l_name) VALUES (2,null,null,null);

commit;
```

```
query result:
                                                                                                                                                                                            

 TABLE_NUM     AMOUNT FIRST_NAME                                                                                           L_NAME                                                                                             
---------- ---------- ---------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------- ----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
         1          1 Luis                                                                                                 Rosas                                                                                               
         1          1 Carlos                                                                                               Borolas                                                                                             
         1          2 Elena                                                                                                Zeta                                                                                                
         1       -1 'N/A'                                                                                                  'N/A'                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                           
         2       -1 'N/A'                                                                                                  'N/A'
```

```
Expected result:


 TABLE_NUM     AMOUNT FIRST_NAME                                                                    L_NAME                                                                                             
---------- ---------- ----------------------------------------------------------------------------- ---------------------------------------------------------------
         1          1 Luis                                                                          Rosas                                                                                               
         1          1 Carlos                                                                        Borolas                                                                                             
         1          2 Elena                                                                         Zeta                                                                                                
         1          2 Elena                                                                         Zeta                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                           
         2          2 Elena                                                                         Zeta
```

sorry for the Spanish table, English it's not my native language.

The question is:

Note: In the last rows I have 'N/A' this is because this values was already null inserted. (I can't insert null values on a table, at least I have to insert something -1 on null numbers and 'n/a' on null varchar2 ), This is already done with code.

2.- How I can replace this """null"""" values with the previous last not """""null"""" values known by the user?

3.- which is better last_value or LAG, and how I can use it? Is it possible to use lag or last value in a complete row?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`NVL` + `LAST_VALUE` might be one option:

```
SQL> select table_num,
  2    nvl(amount, last_value(amount ignore nulls) over (order by table_num)) amount,
  3    nvl(first_name, last_value(first_name ignore nulls) over (order by table_num)) first_name
  4  from tabla_1;

 TABLE_NUM AMOUNT FIRST_NAME
---------- ------ --------------------
         1      1 Carlos
         1      1 Luis
         1      2 Elena
         1      2 Elena
         2      2 Elena

SQL>
```

---

If there aren't `NULL`s (as sample data suggest) but `-1` and `N/A`, then use `CASE`:

```
select table_num, 
  case when amount = -1 then last_value(amount ignore nulls) over (order by table_num)
       else amount
  end amount, 
  --
  case when first_name = 'N/A' then last_value(first_name ignore nulls) over (order by table_num)
       else first_name
  end first_name
from tabla_1
```

Comment: it's not bad at all, but instead of null values on the table i already have -1 and 'N/A' it's possible to adapt your query? to this values instead of null ones?

Comment: Use CASE, then. I added some more code; have a look.